# Build Adobe Air with Java jar file for Android

Tags: air

I am not sure whether this question ever asked here or I am missing it ? Anyway, I think my problem is bit different. Here we go:

1. I have a library (authorization.jar) in Android. This communicates with other service for authorization things.
2. This library (authorization.jar) is used in many other Android applications.
3. Now we are moving to Adobe Air and we need to integrate that authorization.jar in Adobe Air and finally create the APK for Android.
4. We will publish APK only.

How is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with AIR Native Extensions.

It is somewhat complex, but you can find a number of tutorials here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html